# map always both directions in one to many relationship

Tags: database, jpa

Im with some doubts in jpa. For example a table Post and a table Files. A post can have many files associated and one file is associated to one post, so we have a one to many relationship.

Im in doubt to know wether we should create OneToMany relationship or ManyToOne or both. For example  in post and files example, what we need to ask to know if its unidirectional or bidirectional is if we want to know what are the files that a post have and also which files are in a post, right? And if its both yes its a bidirectional relationship, right?. But this two questions seems very similar, so its normal the answer be yes. So its not a good practice map always both directions?

Example, mapping always both directions:

```
@Entity
public class Post{
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="post")
    private List<Files> files= new ArrayList<>();
}

@Entity
public class File{
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private int id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="post_id")
  private Post post;  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This all depends on the requirement and data model. It's not a good or bad practice to make relations bidirectional.

If you want the users to reach to `Files` only through `Post` than make it unidirectional.
Otherwise if you need to provide a functionality to the users to search a File directly and through that users are able to see the Post, make it bidirectional.

In case of bidirectional relationship make sure you create a convenience method to set the relation between `Files` and `Post` and do not forget to use `inverse` attribute.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For example, assuming your first example, if a user can reach some files only trough a post its unidirecitonal. But in this case is OneToMany or ManyToOne? Do you know how to check that?

Comment: @Ozzy In case of unidirectional - You will have a List field of Files in Post and you need to do the mapping in the Post and of-course it will be OneToMany mapping